# Reading blogger entries from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, blogs, blogger

What is the best way to read entries programatically from [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com) using .NET/C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GData](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) has a [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/).  There is a [C# library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html) that can be downloaded.  This is an official library from Google.  I've used it in the past (though in PHP).  The documentation is a bit light, but the code works very well.

Comment: Just perfect. I usually trust google libraries and I guess that the documentation is not a problem because reading blog entries seems to be a driven-by-the-code task. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is absolutely atrocious. It literally has zero pertinent information for anything valuable. Your best bet is to get your FeedQuery and then step through in debugger. Once in the debugger you can see all entities and pick out the ones you want. If you have any questions, post em here, I've been working with this API for the last two weeks.